# Latest Build Tools: What To Use? (Android)

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, version, beta

In Android Studio, when I create a new project, it configures the following in build.gradle(Module:app):

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

But, on the website:

```
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html
```

It seems to be saying that the latest version is 23.0.3.

Is the 24 version some kind of beta?  Is it not a good idea to use version 24 yet?

Comment: It's Android N. You can still compile with version 24. but the `minSdkVersion` should not be set to `24`, as you have to support the Android versions currently available in market.

Comment: Thanks!  I have my minSdk at 16, and target is 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/06/android-n-apis-are-now-final.html) on the google developer's blogs Android N APIs are final and you should be building with them (even though the android N OS hasn't been released to consumers yet). This means you should be using 24 as your compile SDK and as your buildToolsVersion.

Presumably, this was done so developers could get their apps ready for all the android N features before consumers start using it. It is unfortunate that they have not yet updated all their docs but I guess that is one of the challenges of having so many to maintain.